# I need an explanation with File I/O I am recieving warnings I do not understand

Tags: linux, file, pointers, pthreads, posix

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <string.h>


struct string_count_struct{
    char fname;
    char str;
    long long count;

};



void* filesearch(void* arg)
{

    //get the file name
    struct string_count_struct *arg_ptr = (struct string_count_struct*) arg;

    int line_num = 1;
    int find_result = 0;
    char temp[512];


    //create a file pointer 
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen(arg_ptr -> fname, "r");

    //dont forget error handling
    if (fp == NULL){
    printf("File could not be opened");
    return(-1);
    }

    while (fgets(temp, 512, fp) != NULL) {
        if ((strstr(temp, arg_ptr -> str)) != NULL) {
            find_result++;
        }
        line_num++;
    }

    if(find_result = 0) {
        printf("\nSorry, couldn't find a match.\n");
    }

    arg_ptr -> count = find_result;

    //close the file
    if (fp){
        fclose(fp);
    }   

    pthread_exit(0);


}


int main (int argc, char **argv)
{


    if (argc < 3) {
    printf("Usage: <file> <string> <arg1> <arg2>...<argN>\n", argv[0]);
    exit(-1);
    }

    int num_args = argc - 2;

    struct string_count_struct args[num_args];

    //Thread Creation:
    pthread_t tids[num_args];

    for(int i = 0; i < num_args; i++) {
        args[i].fname = atoll(argv[i + 2]);

        pthread_attr_t attr;
        pthread_attr_init(&attr);
        pthread_create(&tids[i], &attr, filesearch, &args[i]);
    }

    //Wait until work is completed
    for (int i = 0; i < num_args; i ++){
    pthread_join(tids[i], NULL);
    printf("blah is blah %lld\n", args[i].count);
    }





return 0;
}
```

Here are my warnings

```
root@kali:~/Desktop# gcc prog2.c -lbthread
prog2.c: In function ‘filesearch’:
prog2.c:29:13: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘fopen’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
  fp = fopen(arg_ptr -> fname, "r");
             ^~~~~~~
In file included from prog2.c:1:0:
/usr/include/stdio.h:274:14: note: expected ‘const char * restrict’ but argument is of type ‘char’
 extern FILE *fopen (const char *__restrict __filename,
              ^~~~~
prog2.c:34:8: warning: return makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
  return(-1);
        ^
prog2.c:38:21: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘strstr’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
   if ((strstr(temp, arg_ptr -> str)) != NULL) {
                     ^~~~~~~
In file included from prog2.c:4:0:
/usr/include/string.h:337:14: note: expected ‘const char *’ but argument is of type ‘char’
 extern char *strstr (const char *__haystack, const char *__needle)
              ^~~~~~
prog2.c: In function ‘main’:
prog2.c:78:17: error: assignment of read-only member ‘fname’
   args[i].fname = atoll(argv[i + 2]);
```

I am unsure of what I am doing wrong, these errors are preventing my program from correctly reading through the desired files and calculating the # of occurrences of a particular string that the user will select. **I have fixed my error but not the warnings**.

The program will take a command line argument, create a separate thread for each file to be searched through, search through each file, and then give the results. I plan on using a Mutex for further refinement, but right now I am just trying to solve my I/O issues.

Answer (score 0):

Just addressing some of the warnings, I'm not at all sure if this will make the code work:

In line 29, fopen expects a filename (`char *`) but fname is just a `char` in string_count_struct. Make it a `char*`. In the main  function you convert one of the arguments from ASCII to `long long` and assign it to fname, which shall later be used as a file name for `fopen()`. That's probably not what you want to do.

In line 34, you return -1 which is not a pointer. You declared the function to be returning a void pointer. Make it return(0) (or return(NULL)).

Same as in line 29 happens in line 38: `str` in the struct string_count_struct is just a `char`, but strstr expects a `char*`. Make it a `char*`, too.

Your "Usage" is missing a "%s" format string to actually print the argument argv[0].

Comment: Thankyou for responding, it is very much appreciated. And your suggestions helped me refine my work